# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/webp

Tags: wordpress, safari, webp

I have a problem on my site, Ive enabled a WebP feature of a wordpress plugin, not knowing it wont work with Safari. Ive then disabled that feature, and made sure that the added code on the htaccess were removed.

Now the site is not displaying images on Safari properly. Error is - "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/webp." I tried to add code to deny webp file type on htaccess out of desperation, still not working.

Is there a way to block serving webp on Safari on htaccess? Or other possible fix. Is this a MIME issue? Thank you.

Comment: what plugin did you use? 
Is this just a cache error?

Comment: Its Short Pixel Optimizer. No i dont think its caching issue because ive deactivated it, also checked htaccess if the codes were removed there.

Comment: well, then it says "all the original images can be restored with a click, either one by one or in bulk"